# What is the best way to trace down memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, c++builder, vcl

In a huge *C++ builder 2010* application with several DLL's being built and linked etc. What would be the best way to trace down memory leaks that accumulate over a long period of time? Say that the application has to be running for a week or something on the target machine before it becomes an issue. Let's assume that there is no profiling application available like AQ Time or something similar. Just using the standard IDE and perhaps some code.

My initial idea was to write a macro to use in all classes that keeps track of the number of instances and space used of each class type to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RTL uses [FastMM](http://fastmm.sourceforge.net) as its memory manager.  FastMM supports memory leak reporting and tracing.  The native version of FastMM that is included in the RTL is a stripped down version, but it does support minimal leak reporting.  You can set the RTL's global [`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) variable to true at run-time and FastMM will generate a basic leak report when the app is closed.  For more advanced usage, you can download the full version of FastMM and add it to your app, which will replace the RTL's native version.  You can then configure FastMM as desired.

Comment: Super, sounds exactly like what I want

Comment: Do you have any good reference about how to replace the standard FastMM for a C++ application? I find some info regarding Delphi but nothing on C++.

Comment: Read the documentation in the "FastMM4BCB.cpp" file in the "CPP Builder Support" subfolder in the downloadable source from the FastMM SourceForge website.

Comment: I did all this (except the USEOBJ which seems deprecated) and it seems to build the extra files for FastMM it talks about. But then it complains about another third party memory manager already being loaded when starting the application. I tried setting "Enable Codeguard" to false if this was causing it but no change.

Comment: Update: When I seemed to get it working by placing the replacement BorlndMM.dll (from the CB2007 directory since there are noone for 2010) I got an error complaining about *hrdir_b.c FATAL memory has been allocated prior to heap redirector hook*

Comment: FastMM has to be installed as the active MM at run-time before any memory is allocated. Make sure to arrange the project's source files in the Project Manager and/or Project makefile so the FastMM source files are compiled first, after the project's main .cpp file but before any other source files. You also need to make sure that `BCB` is defined in your Project Conditionals, or at least in `FastMM4Options.inc` itself, so FastMM will compile with its extra C++ support code enabled.

Comment: I made sure that *FastMM4BCB.cpp* is first in *Options->Build Order*, I have disabled *Code Guard*, added *BCB* to *Options->Delphi Compiler->Conditional defines*, tried every setting possible in *FastMM4Options.inc* but every time I start the application I get same error *"hrdir_b.c FATAL memory has been allocated prior to heap redirector hook"*. The application in question is part of a *Project Group* where a lot of other projects resulting in *.dll* files are also built and used by the application in question. Do all of these HAVE to be changed to include *FastMM* to or what is the problem?

Comment: according to this page: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=22963 ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown will not work. It is unclear if this bug will also effect the full FastMM library.

Comment: @inquam: FastMM can be used on a per-project basis. So no, every project in the group does not need to use FastMM. But in the long run, once you get FastMM working, you will likely WANT to use it in all of your projects. Did you try adding `{$DEFINE BCB}` inside of FastMMOptions.inc itself yet? That's what I ended up doing, but only because all of my full-FastMM-enabled projects are C++.

Comment: @GregorBrandt: that QC report is 8 years old.  Granted, there hve been updates to the report over the years.  But FastMM has been updated over the years to support C++ better. So it could be that the RTL's stripped down version is not working correctly, but the full version should be.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tested with XE3 Update 2. Using full static build with ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown=true in FMXMain, I new and do not delete memory. I get no reports. So the QC is valid.  I'll test with the full FastMM (which currently appears to have a bug under OS X so I can't use it for all my builds anyway).  On another note, using the fastmm supplied borlanmm.dll for the IDE cuts my compiles down significantly, but I get the occasional error because the DLL does not match the 'pirate proofing' in XE3....sigh.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I also tried adding *{$DEFINE BCB}* to the *.inc* file. No difference. Why can't Embarcadero just ship with the full version. My god, this IDE has been nothing but trouble and fixes. If I could go back in time 15-years and tell the people who made the decision to go with C++-Builder back then that it's probably not the best idea I would do it in a heartbeat. The amount of ICE's, memory leaks from the main library itself, IDE crashes etc I have witnessed with C++-builder is probably a factor of ten worse than anything I have ever seen before :) (ok, I'm frustrated... hehe)